# Setup Multiple Custom Domains for Clients using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to give my customers an option to put their website (HTML, CSS, PHP (optional) ) in a custom domain.

By default, customers will get a basic subdomain like: their-site.mydomain.com

If they upgraded to Pro, I wanted to give an option to use custom domain by adding A record or CNAME.

After some google research, I found that lot of companies are using Amazon AWS for this task. However after checking different article, I did not get any idea how this would work with amazon or any other server.

All stuff needs to be done from the my Application UI by customers. There should be atleast 100s or 1000s of domains. I wanted to redirect each of them to their own website.

Any Idea how this will work? Please add all details if possible.

Comment: You mean Domain registration and DNS/routing?

Comment: @saurabh14292 No. Customers will register their domain their own. Just need to route the domain to our service. Think of Webflow or Netlify.